# Three.js: trying to render a custom mesh (rhombic dodecahedron)?

Tags: javascript, three.js, mesh

I'd like to render this:

[image: rhombic dodecahedron - success]

Unfortunately, when I try to create a custom mesh, I get this:

[image: rhombic_dodecahedron - fail]

I came across some old THREE.js code for rendering this solid, but disappointingly, it's only half-useful as it relies on the deprecated THREE.Face4(). So, digging around StackOverflow, I found what I thought to be a work-around using 2 THREE.Face3(). As you saw above, it didn't work. Here's my code.

```
//'2 Face3' to emulate 'Face4' function, thanks to @Kevin Miller and    
  @Jonathan at github.com

function drawSquare(x1, y1, x2, y2) { 
  var square = new THREE.Geometry(); 

  //set 4 points
  square.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( x1,y2,0) );
  square.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( x1,y1,0) );
  square.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( x2,y1,0) );
  square.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( x2,y2,0) );

//push 1 triangle
  square.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0,1,2) );

//push another triangle
  square.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0,3,2) );

//return the square object with BOTH faces
  return square;
};

//rhombic dodecahedron geometry, thanks to http://www.sacred-geometry.es
//vertices
  var vertices = [ new THREE.Vector3( 2.04772293123743050, -4.09327412386437040, -5.74908146957292670),
                   new THREE.Vector3(  7.02732984841516030, 1.40331541320251810, -1.62706516545639390),
                   new THREE.Vector3( 4.22549114271519950, -1.62031854283173550,  5.78962800381778210),
                   new THREE.Vector3( 0.75411577446253997,  7.11690807989861880, -1.66761169970125600),
                   new THREE.Vector3(-0.75411577446252998, -7.11690807989862510,  1.66761169970125020),
                   new THREE.Vector3(-4.22549114271518980,  1.62031854283173260, -5.78962800381778920),
                   new THREE.Vector3( -2.0477229312374288,  4.09327412386436950,  5.74908146957292670),
                   new THREE.Vector3(-7.02732984841515230, -1.40331541320252740,  1.62706516545639970),
                   new THREE.Vector3( 6.27321407395262300, -5.71359266669610030,  0.04054653424485652),
                   new THREE.Vector3( 2.80183870569996340,  3.02363395603425690, -7.41669316927418000),
                   new THREE.Vector3( 4.97960691717773150,  5.49658953706689160,  4.12201630411653590),
                   new THREE.Vector3(-2.80183870569996340, -3.02363395603425690,  7.41669316927418000),
                   new THREE.Vector3(-4.97960691717773150, -5.49658953706689160, -4.12201630411653590),
                   new THREE.Vector3(-6.27321407395262480,  5.71359266669610210, -0.04054653424485653) ];

//faces
  var faces = [ drawSquare(vertices[8],vertices[0],vertices[9],vertices[1]).faces[0],
                drawSquare(vertices[8],vertices[0],vertices[9],vertices[1]).faces[1],
                drawSquare(vertices[8],vertices[1],vertices[10],vertices[2]).faces[0],
                drawSquare(vertices[8],vertices[1],vertices[10],vertices[2]).faces[1],
                drawSquare(vertices[8],vertices[2],vertices[11],vertices[4]).faces[0],
                drawSquare(vertices[8],vertices[2],vertices[11],vertices[4]).faces[1],
                drawSquare(vertices[8],vertices[4],vertices[12],vertices[0]).faces[0],
                drawSquare(vertices[8],vertices[4],vertices[12],vertices[0]).faces[1],
                drawSquare(vertices[12],vertices[5],vertices[9],vertices[0]).faces[0],
                drawSquare(vertices[12],vertices[5],vertices[9],vertices[0]).faces[1],
                drawSquare(vertices[13],vertices[3],vertices[9],vertices[5]).faces[0],
                drawSquare(vertices[13],vertices[3],vertices[9],vertices[5]).faces[1],
                drawSquare(vertices[10],vertices[1],vertices[9],vertices[3]).faces[0],
                drawSquare(vertices[10],vertices[1],vertices[9],vertices[3]).faces[1],
                drawSquare(vertices[10],vertices[3],vertices[13],vertices[6]).faces[0],
                drawSquare(vertices[10],vertices[3],vertices[13],vertices[6]).faces[1],
                drawSquare(vertices[11],vertices[2],vertices[10],vertices[6]).faces[0],
                drawSquare(vertices[11],vertices[2],vertices[10],vertices[6]).faces[1],
                drawSquare(vertices[11],vertices[7],vertices[12],vertices[4]).faces[0],
                drawSquare(vertices[11],vertices[7],vertices[12],vertices[4]).faces[1],
                drawSquare(vertices[12],vertices[7],vertices[13],vertices[5]).faces[0],
                drawSquare(vertices[12],vertices[7],vertices[13],vertices[5]).faces[1],
                drawSquare(vertices[13],vertices[7],vertices[11],vertices[6]).faces[0],
                drawSquare(vertices[13],vertices[7],vertices[11],vertices[6]).faces[1] ];            

//create the mesh 
  var rhombic_dodecahedron_geo = new THREE.Geometry();
    for(c=0; c<vertices.length; c++) { rhombic_dodecahedron_geo.vertices.push( vertices[c] ) };
    for(d=0; d<faces.length; d++) { rhombic_dodecahedron_geo.faces.push( faces[d] ) };

  var rhombic_dodecahedron_mat   = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x4B32AF, wireframe: false} );
      rhombic_dodecahedron       = new THREE.Mesh(rhombic_dodecahedron_geo, rhombic_dodecahedron_mat);

      scene.add(rhombic_dodecahedron);
```

Can anyone spot any errors? Thanks in advance for your help with this frustrating problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the pattern to follow to create a custom polyhedron mesh:

```
// geometry
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

// vertices
geometry.vertices = [
    new THREE.Vector3( 2.04772293123743050, -4.09327412386437040, -5.74908146957292670),
    new THREE.Vector3(  7.02732984841516030, 1.40331541320251810, -1.62706516545639390),
    new THREE.Vector3( 4.22549114271519950, -1.62031854283173550,  5.78962800381778210),
    new THREE.Vector3( 0.75411577446253997,  7.11690807989861880, -1.66761169970125600),
    new THREE.Vector3(-0.75411577446252998, -7.11690807989862510,  1.66761169970125020),
    new THREE.Vector3(-4.22549114271518980,  1.62031854283173260, -5.78962800381778920),
    new THREE.Vector3( -2.0477229312374288,  4.09327412386436950,  5.74908146957292670),
    new THREE.Vector3(-7.02732984841515230, -1.40331541320252740,  1.62706516545639970),
    new THREE.Vector3( 6.27321407395262300, -5.71359266669610030,  0.04054653424485652),
    new THREE.Vector3( 2.80183870569996340,  3.02363395603425690, -7.41669316927418000),
    new THREE.Vector3( 4.97960691717773150,  5.49658953706689160,  4.12201630411653590),
    new THREE.Vector3(-2.80183870569996340, -3.02363395603425690,  7.41669316927418000),
    new THREE.Vector3(-4.97960691717773150, -5.49658953706689160, -4.12201630411653590),
    new THREE.Vector3(-6.27321407395262480,  5.71359266669610210, -0.04054653424485653)
];

// faces - in counterclockwise winding order - important!
geometry.faces.push(
    new THREE.Face3( 8, 0, 9 ),  new THREE.Face3( 9, 1, 8 ),
    new THREE.Face3( 8, 1, 10 ), new THREE.Face3( 10, 2, 8 ),
    new THREE.Face3( 8, 2, 11 ), new THREE.Face3( 11, 4, 8 ),
    new THREE.Face3( 8, 4, 12 ), new THREE.Face3( 12, 0, 8 ),
    new THREE.Face3( 12, 5, 9 ), new THREE.Face3( 9, 0, 12 ),
    new THREE.Face3( 13, 3, 9 ), new THREE.Face3( 9, 5, 13 ),
    new THREE.Face3( 10, 1, 9 ), new THREE.Face3( 9, 3, 10 ),
    new THREE.Face3( 10, 3, 13 ), new THREE.Face3( 13, 6, 10 ),
    new THREE.Face3( 11, 2, 10 ), new THREE.Face3( 10, 6, 11 ),
    new THREE.Face3( 11, 7, 12 ), new THREE.Face3( 12, 4, 11 ),
    new THREE.Face3( 12, 7, 13 ), new THREE.Face3( 13, 5, 12 ),
    new THREE.Face3( 13, 7, 11 ), new THREE.Face3( 11, 6, 13 )
);

// normals ( since they are not specified directly )
geometry.computeFaceNormals();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();

// material - polyhedron requires flat shading
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x479100, shading: THREE.FlatShading } );

// mesh
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( mesh );
```

Be sure to add a light to your scene, since it is required for `Lambert` material.

three.js r.71

Comment: another excellent, thorough answer from @WestLangley. thanks a lot!

Comment: one question: I noticed that you put the faces in order of ascending x-coordinates. does that ensure counter-clockwise winding order, or am I missing something else? thanks in advance.

Comment: No. The vertices of each face must have counterclockwise winding order when the face is facing towards you.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on WestLangley's answers, here's a simplified way of representing a rhombic dodecahedron in threejs.

A rhombic dodecahedron can be constructed by placing a a square pyramid on each face of a square where the square has side length `l` and the square pyramid has height `l/2` (from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RhombicDodecahedron.html)).

[image]

The following code describes the rhombic dodecahedron based on the square that has

- origin at (0, 0, 0)
- rotation (0, 0, 0)
- top face: (A, B, C, D)
- bottom face: (E, F, G, H)
- side length: 2

You'll notice that my dodecahedron has half as many faces as WestLangley's did. That is because each face of the resultant dodecahedron is in fact the union of two adjoining faces of the aforementioned square pyramids. [EDIT: I used Face4 to generate the rhombi but I've just found out that Face4 is deprecated, so each of the rhombi I've created below will need to be replaced with two triangles. Should be pretty obvious how to do that.]

([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6oynre7f/))

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

// vertices
geometry.vertices = [
    new THREE.Vector3( -1,  1, -1 ), // A       (0)
    new THREE.Vector3(  1,  1, -1 ), // B       (1)
    new THREE.Vector3(  1,  1,  1 ), // C       (2)
    new THREE.Vector3( -1,  1,  1 ), // D       (3)
    new THREE.Vector3( -1, -1, -1 ), // E       (4)
    new THREE.Vector3(  1, -1, -1 ), // F       (5)
    new THREE.Vector3(  1, -1,  1 ), // G       (6)
    new THREE.Vector3( -1, -1,  1 ), // H       (7)
    new THREE.Vector3( -2,  0,  0 ), // left    (8)
    new THREE.Vector3(  2,  0,  0 ), // right   (9)
    new THREE.Vector3(  0,  2,  0 ), // top     (10)
    new THREE.Vector3(  0, -2,  0 ), // bottom  (11)
    new THREE.Vector3(  0,  0,  2 ), // front   (12)
    new THREE.Vector3(  0,  0, -2 )  // back    (13)
];


// faces - in counterclockwise winding order
geometry.faces.push(
  new THREE.Face4( 12, 2, 10, 3 ),  // (front, C, top, D)
  new THREE.Face4( 12, 6,  9, 2 ),  // (front, G, right, C)
  new THREE.Face4( 12, 7, 11, 6 ),  // (front, H, bottom, G)
  new THREE.Face4( 12, 3,  8, 7 ),  // (front, D, left, H)
  new THREE.Face4( 13, 5, 11, 4 ),  // (back, F, bottom, E)
  new THREE.Face4( 13, 4,  8, 0 ),  // (back, E, left, A)
  new THREE.Face4( 13, 0, 10, 1 ),  // (back, A, top, B)
  new THREE.Face4( 13, 1,  9, 5 ),  // (back, B, right, F)
  new THREE.Face4(  8, 3, 10, 0 ),  // (left, D, top, A)
  new THREE.Face4(  8, 4, 11, 7 ),  // (left, E, bottom, H)
  new THREE.Face4(  9, 1, 10, 2 ),  // (right, B, top, C)
  new THREE.Face4(  9, 6, 11, 5 )   // (right, G, bottom, F)

);

// normals ( since they are not specified directly )
geometry.computeFaceNormals();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();

// material - polyhedron requires flat shading
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x479100, shading: THREE.FlatShading } );

// mesh
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( mesh );
```